# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre on.click y click?

Tags: jquery

Pues eso, ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los dos métodos? ¿Semánticamente es lo mismo o afecta en algo?

```js
$('#demo').on('click', function() {
  alert('Click con on.click');
});

$('#demo2').click(function() {
  alert('Click con click');
});
```

```css
#demo{
  background-color:#F2F2F2;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:table-cell;
  cursor:pointer;
}

#demo2{
  background-color:#E6E6E6;
  width:500px;
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display:table-cell;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">Click con on.click</div>
<div id="demo2">Click con click</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tal vez la diferencia más importante radica en que `.on('click', selector, function(){})` permite trabajar con elementos agregados después de haber cargado el DOM, mientras que con `.click(function(){})` esto no es posible.

```js
$('#test1').on('click', '.demoOnClick',function() {                  
  console.log('Click con on.click');
});

$('.demoClick').click(function() {
  console.log('Click con click');
});

$('#crearBoton').click(function() {
  $('#test1').append('<div class="demoOnClick">Clic para On.click</div><div class="demoClick">Clic para .click</div>');
});
```

```css
#crearBoton {
  border: solid 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
}

.demoOnClick {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.demoClick {
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test1">
  
  </div>
<div id="crearBoton">Clic aqui</div>
```

---

Otras diferencias:

- `.on()` crea un solo handler para todos los elementos incluidos en el selector, mientras que `.click()` crea un handler para cada uno de estos elementos.
- `on()` permite el uso de namespaces.

Comment: Me gusto la respuesta pero ¿Cómo permite trabajar con elementos después de cargarse el DOM? ¿podrías poner un ejemplo? Por favor :)

Comment: Se llama "delegar eventos", otro ejemplo : https://jsfiddle.net/m8hxkduc/

Comment: Muchas gracias, @Shaz y Jose Hermosilla. Quiero suponer que aplica en todos los métodos qué dices, ¿Verdad? Por ejemplo on('mouseover')

Answer (score 1):

me gustaría agregar algo con respecto a este tema.
El método `.on` permite delegación de eventos, pero también se puede usar como `listener` directo variando la sintaxis.

El tema está en proporcionarle un selector en la llamada.
Así:

`$(document).on('click', myEventHandler)` va a escuchar todos los clicks de todo el documento.

`$('#myElement').on('click', myEventHandler)` va a escuchar todos los clicks de todos los elementos descendientes de myElement (y de sí mismo).

`$('#myElement').on('click', '.mySelector', myEventHandler)` lo que hace es lo mismo que el anterior pero luego filtra por `.mySelector` antes de llamar a `myEventHandler`.

Entonces:
`$('#myElement').on('click', myEventHandler)` es exactamente lo mismo que

```
$('#myElement').click(myEventHandler)
```

El porqué de que `on` "permite trabajar con elementos agregados después de haber cargado el DOM" es que en realidad hay un `listener` para ese evento declarado en un elemento de nivel inferior que lo está abarcando.

Más claro:

```
$('#myDIV').on('click', 'button', myEventHandler)
```

En realidad el que está recibiendo el evento es el `listener` declarado para `myDIV`, luego filtra por selector a todos los elementos `button` que contiene.

Por eso es que al agregar un nuevo elemento button a `myDIV` éste reacciona al evento `click`.

Fácil! ;)

Un ejemplo cotidiano.
Cuando usamos un componente de algún `framework` como por ejemplo un `alert` de `Bootstrap`.
Vemos que al agregar dinámicamente la alerta al DOM con el atributo `data-dismiss="alert"` automáticamente el botón close hace que la alerta se cierre sin necesidad de *attachearle* un `listener`.
Eso es porque internamente la librería js de Bootstrap lo que hace es:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-dismiss="alert"]', myHandler).
```

Luego `myHandler` hace el `dismiss` de el elemento de clase `alert` más cercano (método `jQuery.closest`), etc.

Cómo hace `jQuery` para identificar en el botón de qué alerta se hizo click?
Gracias al `event bubbling`...
Si bien el `listener` fue establecido en el elemento raíz (`document`), en realidad el evento `click` se produjo en el botón de la alerta y fue bajando hasta que lo recibió `document`.
Luego `jQuery` filtró todas las `alerts` y llamó al `handler` mediante el método `apply` de `javascript` y pasándole como parámetro el elemento que originó el evento (el `button`).

Cuando utilizamos `$(document).on('click', 'button.myClass', myHandler)` `jQuery` lo que hace internamente es `document.addEventListener('click', myHandler, false)`.

O sea que captura todos los `clicks` de todos los objetos de la página y luego hace el `dispatch` hacia el objeto `button.myClass`.