# ¿Como elimino una entrada con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estoy creando una app de tareas con jQuery, para practicar nada más pero tengo un problema a la hora de eliminar una tarea, aquí les dejo el código espero puedan ayudarme

El código jQuery es:

```
$(".agregarBtn").click(function(){

   var texto  = $(".agregarTxt").val();
   var cuadro = $('<div></div>').text(texto);
   var boton  = $("<button class='btn-delete'>Eliminar</button>");
   cuadro.attr("class","tarea");
   cuadro.append(boton);
   $(".tareas_nuevas").prepend(cuadro);
   $(".agregarTxt").val("");
   $(".btn-delete").fadeOut();
});

$(".btn-erase").click(function(){
    $(".btn-delete").fadeToggle();
});

//Esta es la función para eliminar las tareas 
$(".btn-delete").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().slideUp();
});
```

Código HTML

```
<div class="entrada">
  <input class="agregarTxt" type="text" placeholder="Entrada nueva"/>
  <button class="agregarBtn">Agregar</button>
  <button class="btn-erase">Eliminar tareas</button>
</div>
<div class="tareas_nuevas">
 <!--AQUI VAN LAS TAREAS NUEVAS-->
</div>
```

Comment: Cuando le doy eliminar no pasa nada 

Comment: El problema es que asocias el evento del borrado antes de crear el propio botón de borrado. Busca qué son los [eventos delegados en jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+delegados) y encontrarás respuestas que te servirán.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola!

Veo varios problemas en tu código de jQuery.

Primeramente, estás usando funciones/métodos que no sirven para eliminar del DOM los elementos, si no para ocultarlos, los cuales son [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/), [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) y [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/), cada uno de estos métodos oculta los elementos de diferente manera y los cuales puedes leer en la documentación de jQuery.

Los métodos que tu debes de utilizar para eliminar son [empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) y [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Otro problema que veo, es que no estas utilizando la **delegación de eventos**, la cual te permite trabajar con elementos agredados después de haberse cargado el DOM. Para más información sobre eso, [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22830/12625).

Y como consejo, primero aprende a saber que es el DOM, así sabrás como moverte a través de el por medio de jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".agregarBtn").click(function(){

     var texto  = $(".agregarTxt").val();
     var cuadro = $('<div></div>').text(texto);
     var boton  = $("<button class='btn-delete'>Eliminar</button>");
     cuadro.attr("class","tarea");
     cuadro.append(boton);
     $(".tareas_nuevas").prepend(cuadro);
     $(".agregarTxt").val("");
     //$(".btn-delete").fadeOut();
  });

  $(".btn-erase").click(function(){
      //$(".btn-delete").fadeToggle();
      $('.tareas_nuevas').empty();
  });

  //Esta es la función para eliminar las tareas 
  /*$(".btn-delete").click(function(){
    //$(this).parent().slideUp();
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });*/
  
  $('.tareas_nuevas').on('click', '.btn-delete', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="entrada">
  <input class="agregarTxt" type="text" placeholder="Entrada nueva"/>
  <button class="agregarBtn">Agregar</button>
  <button class="btn-erase">Eliminar tareas</button>
</div>
<div class="tareas_nuevas">
 <!--AQUI VAN LAS TAREAS NUEVAS-->
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, no tenía conocimiento del .on() ya puede por fin terminarlo 