# Botón para agregar productos en lista

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, bootstrap

Hola el estoy desarrolando un pequeño proyecto el cual contiene desde conexiones a base datos, estilos y demas, pero al dia de hoy me he topado con un problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen de arriba tengo una lista de articulos el cual tiene hasta el final el apartado de "Accciones" el cual planeo hacer que este botón al darle clic me genere una lista como se ve más abajo (ojo: esa la puse yo manualmente como ejemplo, pues es asi como quiero que se vea), pero he investigado y no he logrado encontrar un complemento o código de ayuda que me de una idea de generar dicho código, ¿como podria hacerle para que me genere una lista asi como en la imagen?

Cabe recalcar que son datos de una base de datos y codigo php que muestran dichos resultados de la tabla.

Les agredeceria la ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me basare en las etiquetas que pusiste para realizar tu pregunta.

La manera que se me ocurre es a partir de AJAX. Que si no tienes una idea, puedes revisar su documentación en jQuery [aquí](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Lo primero que tendrías que hacer son modificaciones en tu primer tabla, donde tendrías que poner el ID del artículo (que supongo ese ID del artículo lo obtienes de tu base de datos), ponlo en tu HTML para después tomarlo con jQuery y poder hacer la petición AJAX.

Muy bien, ¿Y ahora donde hago la petición AJAX?
Para hacer la petición AJAX tendrás que crear un archivo PHP donde obtendrás los parametros a través del método GET y ahí podrías hacer tu consulta a la BDD a partir de los parametros, crear un array, convertirlo a JSON y retornar el JSON.

Después en tu script de JS, deberás crear el método AJAX con su respectiva 'configuración' (Puedes ver el ejemplo aquí abajo), quizás aún no tengas una url pero puedes añadir la ruta (junto con el archivo PHP) donde se encuentra. Ej: back/php/obtenerMasDetallesArticulos.php

Te dejo un ejemplo de como hice una petición AJAX a una API de Meetup a partir de la primera tabla y como fui añadiendo más información a la segunda tabla.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.add').click(function(){
    
    /*
    ** Obtengo el ID del pais del elemento padre
    ** del boton al que le doy clic
    */
    let id_country = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    /*
    ** Creo una variable con la URL a la que
    ** mandaré la petición y le concateno la variable id_country
    */
    let url = `https://api.meetup.com/2/cities?&country=${id_country}&page=1`;
    /*
    ** Creo una funcion AJAX de tipo GET donde
    ** configuro sus valores.
    ** type = tipo de método. Ej: POST o GET
    ** url = url donde haré la petición
    ** success = Si la información es correcta, me la retorna de la url donde hice la petición
    ** dataType = El tipo de dato que esperamos del servidor.
    ** jsonp por que hacemos una petición a un dominio diferente
    */
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      success: function(data)
      {
        //console.log(data);
        let ciudad = data['results'][0]['city'];
        let id_ciudad = data['results'][0]['id'];
        let pais = data['results'][0]['localized_country_name'];
        
        let html = `
          <tr>
            <td>${id_ciudad}</td>
            <td>${ciudad}</td>
            <td>${pais}</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="deleteCity">Eliminar</button></td>
          </tr>
        `;
        
        $('#details-country tbody').append(html); //Insertamos la fila al cuerpo de la segunda tabla.
      },
      dataType: 'jsonp',
    });
    
  });
  
  //Delegación de eventos.
  $('#details-country tbody' ).on( "click", ".deleteCity", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:20px;">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>
               <td>País</td>
               <td>Acciones</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td >US</td>
              <td id="us">
                <button type="button" class="add">Ver ciudad</button>                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>MX</td>
              <td id="mx">
                <button type="button" class="add">Ver ciudad</button>                    </td>
            </tr>           
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="details-country">
          <tr>
             <td>ID ciudad</td>
             <td>Ciudad</td>
             <td>País</td>
             <td>Acción</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDITO:**
La eliminación tiene que ser a través de la delegación de eventos, para saber más sobre este tema puedes ir a la siguiente pregunta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/99256/como-elimino-una-entrada-con-jquery/99268#99268).

Comment: Si es exactemente lo que buscaba, ahora tengo un detatillito, como elimino de la lista las que ya agregue(desde la lista que se va creando) como quedaria eso ? jeje peron por la molestia.

Comment: Las quieres eliminar a partir de un boton o dando clic sobre el registro?

Comment: apartir de un boton jeje

Comment: @SantiagoHuh ¡Listo! Tienes que delegar el evento, arriba te dejo donde puedes conseguir más información. Si te sirvio mi respuesta, marcala como correcta para que más personas puedan dar más fácil y rápido con la información. Saludos.

Comment: ha quedado bien jeje he logrado unirlos y eliminarlo de manera exitosa, pero ahora tengo otro problema, me podrias pasar un numero de contacto para que te explique mejor ? perdon la molestia.

Comment: Listo correo enviado. :)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que emplees DataTables Editor, ya que con esta herramienta podrás realizar tu app de forma rápida y sin tantas complicaciones [DataTables](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple.html)

Comment: Revisar [answer].