# Como logro hacer que mi boton no pierda funcionalidad despues de agregarlo con append en jquery

Tags: html, jquery, materialize

Con esto agrego una fila a mi tabla esta fila contiene datos y botones. Pero los botones dejan de funcionar me toca recargar la pagina para que funcionen.

como hago para que funcionen sin recargar la pagina ya después de agregados con append

```
$("tbody#agregarusuario").append('<tr><td><input id="obtenerid" type="number" value="'+obj.id_usuario+'" hidden>'+obj.nombres+'</td><td>'+obj.apellidos+'</td><td>'+obj.correo+'</td><td>'+obj.id_tipo_usuario+'</td><td>'+obj.habilitado+'</td><td><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal'+obj.id_usuario+'" style="border-radius: 34px;height: 50px;"><i class="material-icons left" style="margin-right: 0px;position: relative;top: 6px;">edit</i></a></td><td><div id="eliminarusuarios" name="btn_eliminar" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" style="border-radius: 34px;height: 50px;"><i class="material-icons left" style="margin-right: 0px;position: relative;top: 6px;">close</i></div></td>');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

utiliza el metodo on para asignar los eventos ejemplo:

```
$('tbody').on('click',selector,function(){
```

Comment: Importante mencionar que ".clase" debe tenerla el botón al que quieres agregarle el evento.

Comment: lo que pasa es que el td que se agrega con esos botones ya tiene su funcion click, y los td que estan con botones funcionan. los que no funcionan son los que se agregan con append. creo que tiene que ver con algo del DOM por que ya esta cargado. pero no se como darle solucion.

Comment: @AlbertoJulioArceEscolar creo que la solución para tu problema es mi respuesta te dejo una fuente que te lo explica mejor https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22829/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-on-click-y-click