# Mi append en jquery no hereda las funciones anteriormente definidas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Necesito que los append hereden mi funcion add_data para poder llamarla con el evento onclick.
Los elementos append son añadidos mediante un for, mi códido es el siguiente:

Necesito que los append hereden mi funcion add_data para poder llamarla con el evento onclick.
Los elementos append son añadidos mediante un for, mi códido es el siguiente:

Necesito que los append hereden mi funcion add_data para poder llamarla con el evento onclick.
Los elementos append son añadidos mediante un for, mi códido es el siguiente:

```
for(var i in info.data){

                        console.log(info.data[i]);


                        $( ".products-list" ).append("<div class='product-item item_busqueda' id='"+info.data[i].idproducto+"' category='Busqueda'><img src='"+info.data[i].imagen+"'><a href='#'>"+info.data[i].nombreproducto+"</a><br><p>RD$ "+info.data[i].precio+"</p><a id='add_carrito' pid='"+info.data[i].id+"' onclick='add_data()' href='#' class='clickcart'  ><i class='fas fa-cart-plus'></i></a></div>");




                    }


function add_data(){

                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("!2222");
                var idcc = $(this).attr('pid');


                        $.ajax({
                                    url: './backend/datosmodal.php',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    async: true,
                                    data: {idcc:idcc},


                                    success: function(response){
                                    var infor = JSON.parse(response);

                                    $("#img_modal").attr("src",infor.imagen);

                                    $("#name_modal").html(infor.nombreproducto);

                                    $('.modal').fadeIn();




                                    }, 

                                    error: function(error) {
                                    console.log(error);

                                    }

                                    });


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

aqui te dejo una clara idea de como puedes hacerlo. A mi me funciono de esta manera [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre on.click y click?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22829/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-on-click-y-click)